# How to left justify the output of each column in SQL?

Tags: sqlplus

[image]

When I run the query above, I get:

[image]

As you can see the output for MENU_ID is left justified while the output for all other columns are right justified. How can I left justify the output for all columns? By the way, I am using Oracle SQLPLUS.